# Rendering 2 separate arrays in Dust.js

Tags: javascript, dust.js

So im trying to render a dust template with two separate arrays.  My data is something like:

```
{
    array1: [5, 10, 20],
    array2: [10, 20, 40]
}
```

And my dust template looks like:

```
{#array1}
<div class="span2">
  <input type="number" value={.}></div>
<div class="span2">
  <input type="number" value={array2[{$idx}]}></div>
</div>{~n}
{/array1}
```

It displays the elements from array1 fine, but all the inputs for array2 are blank.  I'm using dust-full-1.2.2.js linkedIn fork.  What should I do to be able to display the values of array2?

Comment: i found this: https://github.com/linkedin/dustjs/issues/207 hopefully theyre gonna fix it sometime soon, but its been 3 months

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Dust way to do this is to change the data (if that's possible):

```
{
    numbers: [
        {val1: 5, val2: 10},
        {val1: 10, val2: 20},
        {val1: 20, val2: 40}
    ]
}
```

Then your template would look like this:

```
{#numbers}
  <div class="span2">
    <input type="number" value="{val1}"></div>
  <div class="span2">
    <input type="number" value="{val2}"></div>
  </div>
{/numbers}
```

Comment: I've seen in the documentation that its possible to access elements of an array that you pass to dust, so why should I need to change my data?  I can do that but I would prefer not to.

Answer (score 0):

Please let me know if this could work for you.
http://jsfiddle.net/yXx5L/3/

Im using a helper to fill the second text box value without changing the data format.

```
value={#counterpart i=$idx}{ele}{/counterpart}
```

Answer (score 0):

change the context to Array2. Add {#array2[...]}

Refer to Explicit context setting here : https://github.com/linkedin/dustjs/wiki/Dust-Tutorial